# Aurelia Ajax AutoComplete for jQuery

Tags: jquery, aurelia

Iam trying to use Ajax AutoComplete for jQuery in my Aurelia app. I cant access an object selected through autocomplete.
This is my js code.

```
this.questionPaperLookup = $('#question-paper-list').autocomplete({
  lookup: this.questionPaperLookupData,
  minChars : 0,
  onSelect: function (suggestion) {
    this.selectedQuestionPaper = suggestion.data;
  }
});
```

Here iam setting **selectedQuestionPaper** based on selection from autocomplete.
And trying to access this object from its html like this:

```
<span id = "selected-question-paper" class="auto_text selected_batches">
            ${selectedQuestionPaper.name}
          </span>
```

But name property of selectedQuestionPaper object is not displaying in view. I dont know any required step is missing. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You must use arrow functions to have the lexical `this`:

```
this.questionPaperLookup = $('#question-paper-list').autocomplete({
  lookup: this.questionPaperLookupData,
  minChars : 0,
  onSelect: (suggestion) => {
    this.selectedQuestionPaper = suggestion.data;
  }
});
```

Comment: The problem still exist after using arrow function

Comment: Put a debugger before ` this.selectedQuestionPaper = suggestion.data;` see if it's being hit

Comment: Yes. I can print the object properties to console likeconsole.log(this.selectedQuestionPaper.name); It prints selected question paper name

Comment: Hmm that is strange... After the select event, can you make sure that the viewModel's property contains the desired value?